# URL Patterns in Django - Different Combinations

Tags: django, url-pattern

I'm finding it hard to understand what exactly is passed to the `patterns` method in Django.

You see, I usually have my `urls.py` as:

```
urlspatterns = patterns('example.views',

    (r'/$','func_to_call'),

)
```

Then in `func_to_call` I would get everything I want from the `request` object by using `request.path`. However on a second take, it's really quite horrific that I'm ignoring Django's slickness for such a longer, less clean way of parsing - the reason being I don't understand what to do!

Let's say you have 3 servers you're putting your Django application on, all of which have a domain name and some variation like `server1/djangoApplicationName/queryparams`, `server2/application/djangoApplicationName` and `server3/queryparams`. What will the `urlpattern` get passed? The whole url? Everything after the domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLconf regex sees only the path portion of the URL, with the initial forward-slash stripped. Query parameters are not matched by the URLconf, you access those via request.GET in your view. So you might write a pattern like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^myapp/something/$', 'something_view_func')
)
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/) has more examples and details.

Comment: Your link is broken, please, could you modify it?